# Camera Calibration using tennis court dimensions

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, computer-vision, homography

I am working on a [tennis project](https://github.com/artLabss/tennis-tracking) and currently trying to find the places on the court where the ball touches the court. 
Currently I have:

- `x,y` coordinates of the ball from the these [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11FqSEN_HIhzM3OZ22WoZHJnW1rvbnz4y/view?usp=sharing) (P.S. x,y coordinates are in the following [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmd4n.png)).

```html
points = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [985, 325], [978, 345], None, None, None, None, None, [904, 613], [895, 644], [886, 649], [877, 654], [870, 658], [870, 658], [861, 664], [853, 672], [846, 679], [837, 688], [827, 695], [827, 695], [821, 707], [812, 716], [803, 729], [1051, 313], [786, 755], [786, 755], [782, 769], [782, 746], [786, 730], [793, 700], [800, 677], [800, 677], [803, 656], [807, 640], [814, 620], [819, 593], [819, 579], [819, 579], [825, 562], [831, 546], [834, 532], None, [833, 805], [833, 805], None, None, None, None, None, None, [865, 427], [867, 418], [871, 409], [872, 400], [877, 392], [877, 392], [877, 385], [883, 377], [883, 369], [887, 366], [890, 358], [890, 357], [892, 352], [894, 346], [897, 340], [898, 336], [900, 332], [900, 332], [902, 329], [905, 325], [905, 322], [908, 320], [910, 316], [910, 316], [912, 315], [914, 314], [916, 310], [919, 308], [919, 306], [919, 306], [920, 305], [924, 306], [922, 306], [926, 305], [928, 305], [926, 307], [930, 306], [930, 305], [932, 305], [933, 307], [935, 310], [935, 308], [936, 310], [937, 313], [938, 314], [940, 316], [942, 319], [942, 319], [942, 322], [943, 323], [945, 324], [946, 316], [945, 306], [945, 306], [945, 298], [946, 291], [947, 284], [947, 278], [950, 272], [949, 273], [950, 266], [951, 261], [950, 255], [950, 251], [951, 245], [951, 245], [953, 241], [952, 237], [950, 236], [945, 237], [939, 240], [938, 239], [934, 242], [928, 244], [922, 250], [917, 252], [911, 256], [911, 256], [905, 263], [899, 267], [896, 274], [890, 278], [883, 286], [883, 286], [878, 293], [873, 300], [869, 309], [863, 318], [858, 329], [858, 329], [851, 338], [846, 349], [840, 359], [835, 371], [830, 384], [830, 384], [825, 397], [818, 410], [812, 424], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [774, 535], [773, 537], [768, 550], [761, 572], [754, 592], [750, 615], [748, 624], [748, 624], [739, 652], [733, 674], [728, 698], [727, 718], [718, 733], [718, 733], [714, 732], [709, 729], [705, 728], [702, 729], [694, 728], [696, 728], [692, 728], [688, 730], [684, 730], [678, 731], [675, 734], [675, 734], [673, 737], [667, 741], [664, 743], [659, 749], [653, 755], [653, 755], [650, 759], [647, 765], [642, 774], [636, 780], [633, 786], [633, 787], [630, 796], [625, 804], [629, 769], [634, 737], [633, 718], [633, 718], [640, 697], [644, 657], [649, 640], [651, 616], [655, 592], [654, 591], [654, 578], [656, 560], [659, 544], [662, 525], None, None, None, [668, 482], None, None, [675, 448], [675, 448], None, [677, 427], [677, 419], [678, 410], [678, 404], [678, 404], [679, 394], [682, 394], [682, 385], [682, 380], [683, 374], [683, 374], [684, 370], [684, 367], [684, 364], [685, 361], [686, 359], [686, 359], [686, 357], [686, 356], [687, 353], [686, 353], [687, 352], [687, 352], [688, 350], [687, 339], [685, 329], [687, 318], [686, 309], [687, 309], [681, 300], [686, 293], [688, 283], [689, 273], [688, 268], [689, 270], [689, 261], [688, 256], [688, 250], [689, 243], [688, 238], [688, 238], [690, 237], [690, 231], [690, 228], [691, 226], [696, 227], [699, 226], [705, 227], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [758, 234], [758, 234], [762, 239], [769, 241], [775, 243], [780, 246], [787, 250], [787, 250], [793, 253], [800, 256], [806, 261], [812, 263], [820, 266], [820, 266], [826, 271], [832, 274], [840, 279], [845, 283], [851, 289], [852, 289], [858, 296], [866, 299], [874, 306], [879, 312], [888, 318], [888, 318], [893, 323], [900, 330], [908, 338], [914, 344], [922, 350], [922, 350], [928, 360], [937, 367], [945, 378], [950, 384], None, None, [967, 402], [974, 411], [980, 421], [989, 428], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1054, 518], [1061, 533], [1066, 543], [1076, 557], [1077, 558], [1087, 569], [1093, 585], [1101, 601], [1110, 614], [1119, 629], [1119, 629], [1128, 642], [1136, 662], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1211, 723], [1216, 718], [1220, 719], [1226, 719], [1227, 718], [1232, 718], [1238, 719], [1243, 721], [1252, 721], [1256, 721], [1256, 721], [1262, 725], [1268, 728], [1273, 731], [1280, 734], [1286, 737], [1286, 737], [1293, 742], [1298, 746], [1305, 749], None, [1299, 691], [1299, 691], [1295, 668], [1295, 649], [1288, 623], [1285, 597], [1280, 571], [1280, 571], [1277, 552], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1254, 430], [1249, 417], [1249, 417], [1246, 409], [1242, 399], [1239, 392], [1237, 384], [1234, 379], [1234, 379], [1231, 373], [1230, 367], [1227, 364], [1225, 361], [1222, 358], [1222, 358], [1220, 356], [1219, 353], [1214, 353], [1212, 352], [1209, 350], [1209, 350], [1207, 351], [1206, 350], [1204, 352], [1202, 350], [1202, 335], [1202, 335], [1200, 324], [1198, 313], None, [1194, 292], [1195, 281], [1195, 281], [1194, 273], [1191, 263], [1191, 256], [1191, 247], [1190, 239], [1190, 239], [1189, 234], [1189, 228], [1189, 221], [1188, 216], [1186, 213], [1187, 212], [1184, 209], [1183, 205], [1182, 200], [1181, 195], [1181, 195], [1181, 195], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [908, 212], [906, 222], [901, 235], [900, 235], [898, 249], [893, 263], [888, 276], [883, 292], [878, 303], [879, 303], [876, 321], [857, 673], [866, 349], [863, 365], [859, 384], [859, 384], [855, 398], [851, 411], [849, 412], [845, 413], [841, 414], [841, 414], [837, 414], [835, 413], [830, 415], [828, 416], [825, 416], [825, 416], [821, 419], [817, 421], [816, 424], [813, 425], [809, 423], [809, 423], [805, 405], [804, 378], [803, 360], [799, 340], [800, 324], [800, 324], [838, 625], None, [793, 274], [791, 259], [788, 248], [788, 248], [787, 235], [783, 224], [783, 214], [781, 204], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [856, 617], [857, 617], [860, 617], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [808, 210], [814, 226], [818, 239], [820, 238], [824, 250], [830, 260], [836, 275], [839, 286], None, None, [852, 321], [858, 334], [860, 350], [868, 366], [875, 383], [875, 383], [880, 402], [885, 418], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [975, 558], [991, 561], [991, 561], None, [997, 579], None, None, None, None, None, [1017, 577], None, [1028, 565], [942, 433], [942, 433], [943, 424], [944, 420], [946, 412], [949, 407], [948, 401], [948, 401], [948, 397], [949, 391], [950, 391], [952, 385], [954, 381], [954, 381], [954, 378], [954, 375], [955, 372], [956, 371], [956, 368], [956, 368], [956, 368], [960, 365], [959, 363], [960, 364], [961, 364], [961, 364], [963, 363], [963, 364], [962, 364], [965, 365], [967, 367], [967, 367], [967, 367], [966, 370], [966, 371], [968, 374], [969, 377], [969, 377], [969, 381], [969, 384], [969, 388], None, [972, 394], [972, 394], [971, 399], [972, 404], [973, 409], [972, 414], [973, 418], [973, 418], [973, 424], [973, 430], [972, 437], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [973, 430], [974, 423], [974, 416], [974, 411], [974, 407], [974, 407], [973, 403], [972, 396], None, [971, 389], [973, 385], [973, 385], [972, 384], [973, 379], [972, 377], [971, 374], [972, 373], [973, 373], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [957, 372], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [946, 412], [941, 413], [935, 414], [936, 414], [929, 414], [922, 413], [914, 414], [908, 416], [902, 417], [902, 417], [894, 418], [889, 422], [882, 424], [873, 425], [867, 428], [867, 428], [861, 436], [853, 437], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [743, 536], [738, 543], [732, 552], [732, 545], [732, 545], [734, 532], None, None, [701, 583], None, None, None, None, None, [766, 425], [770, 413], [769, 414], [774, 405], [776, 392], [780, 384], [783, 374], [788, 363], [788, 363], [791, 354], [794, 346], [799, 339], [802, 331], [805, 324], [805, 324], [808, 319], [813, 312], [814, 304], [818, 299], [824, 295], [824, 295], [828, 288], [828, 285], [832, 280], [835, 276], [838, 274], [838, 274], [842, 269], [846, 266], [848, 265], [852, 262], [855, 260], [855, 260], [857, 259], [861, 256], None, [868, 253], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1081, 594], [1091, 586], [1091, 586], [1103, 573], [1113, 564], [1126, 553], [1140, 542], [1150, 533], [1150, 533], [1163, 523], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

These points on the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/118i4BUbn1ddilS_41R2YffnznJT-8H1T/view?usp=sharing).

- 4 points of the court corners and 2 points under the net
  `upperLeft = (577, 303)`

  `upperRight = (1333, 303)`
  `bottomLeft = (366, 857)`
  `bottomRight = (1562, 857)`
  `netLeft = (495, 517)`
  `netRight = (1422, 517)`

[image: asd]

- and court dimensions 23,7 by 10.97 meters.

I was told that this information is not enough, therefore, I have to find the ball's 3D trajectory. Using this [paper](http://www.shenlj.cn/en/Shen_CP2M_iscss2015.pdf) as my main guide I tried to do that.

However, I got stuck at camera calibration (**section 2.1**) I don't know how can I get 3D projection/model of the court like on this picture
[image]

I hope I clearly described the question and the information at hand. Any pointer, advice or question is appreciated.

Comment: since the ball is basically a tiny blob, you can't extract 3d information here. stick with tracking the ball, getting 2d points, and detecting where those trajectories "kink", which is when the ball hits something and changes direction. then assume that the ball only bounces off the floor, nothing else. then you can transform those 2d screen locations onto the 3d plane of the tennis court. this is still 2d, because the court is a flat plane, but the transformation is a homography that maps screen coordinates to coordinates on the court.

Answer (score 1):

There two separate questions that can be answered:

1. Given pixel locations of where the ball bounces, and of 6 known points on the court, can you estimate the 3D location of where the ball bounces? Answer: Yes. This is because the court (if it is a standard one) has known dimensions, which determine the scale of the homography between the plane of the court and the image. Simplest way to proceed is to use the 1-image minimal version of Zhang's camera calibration algorithm (as implemented in OpenCv) to estimate just the focal length and the camera location and orientation with respect to the 6 on-court points. Once the camera is calibrated, all you have to do is to intersect the 3d ray backprojecting the ball bounce point with the plane at Z=0
2. Given observations of the ball's trajectory, can you estimate the pixel location of the bounce (if one exists)? Answer: it depends. This is purely an image processing problem, boiling down to finding discontinuities in the observed velocity vector of the ball over time. Velocity estimation is notoriously noisy, and will partly depend on the camera orientation with respect to the ball's trajectory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I would like to find the pixel location of the bounce, . Having the `x,y` (2D from the video) coordinates, how can I estimate the velocity over time so I can look for discontinuities?

Comment: You'll need to experiment with numerical estimation methods for the partial derivatives of the pixel position. Start with finite differences, and go wild from there...